# Running Xvfb in LXD container

Tags: linux, headless-browser, lxd

It is easy to run GUI application inside LXD container (ubuntu:16.04) with Xvfb and executing the bellow commands inside the container:

```
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1600x900x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99
firefox &
```

My objective is to execute above commands without logging in, and automatically when I start the container (lxc start ).

I tried to create a script in "/etc/init.d/my-script", and make it executable. But no chance, it didn't work ([Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/how-do-i-start-xvfb-on-startup-on-debian)).

Also when I try to execute `lxc exec <container_name> -- Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1600x900x24 &` inside the host, it immediately stops.

I appreciate if you share your solutions.

Comment: To see the GUI running with Xvfb, do you need VNC? I think VNC is also need for X11 isolation. I am using an LXC container but it should be similar to LXD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run the bash command using "nohup" so bash continues to run in the background.

Example: lxc exec container -- nohup bash -c "Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1600x900x24 &"

See: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html